# Can 'that' ever modify book in these sentences?

Tags: phrase-usage, possessives, determiners

Can *that* (either separately or as the first word of a phrase) modify "book" in the following:

1

> I have never heard of that Jane Austen's book.

I.e., can the sentence be equivalent to

> I have never heard of that book of Jane Austen's.

2
What about

> I can't find that boy's book.

Can "that" modify book? If it can, is it any different than Sentence 1?

Answer (score 3):

*That* in all of these sentences acts as a determiner. Determiners are words like *the*, *a/an*, *some*, *many* which stand at the beginning of a noun phrase and "determine" which member or members of the 'set' which the noun names is in play.

Possessives also act as determiners. Since ordinarily only one determiner is permitted in each noun phrase, *that Jane Austen's book* is ungrammatical (except in the unlikely case that your discourse is about two or more Jane Austens). That's why you have to use your second example, in which *of Jane Austen's* is an ordinary modifier, not a determiner.

*That boy's book*, however, **is** acceptable, because in this case *that* is taken to be a determiner on *boy*, not *book*: not *that book of the boy* but *the book of that boy*.

Comment: That Stoney B! Don't you just love that Stoney B's writing style .... :) (Not sure there's two SB's there!)

Comment: @Araucaria True. Also "Man, I do love me some mama's fried chicken", where the determiner's dependency is less ambiguous. Art and rhetoric depend on breaking rules, which can't happen if the rules aren't in place.

Comment: How can you say it's LESS  ambiguous? Does he love only HIS mama's chicken, or is any ("some") mama's chicken just as lovable?  I would actually favor the latter, because "mama's" is not capitalized—but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock In my dialect, at least, there's no ambiguity: the stress/pitch profiles are completely different.

Comment: Sorry, those "stress profiles" didn't come through in print.  Funny how that happens.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock That's a chronic problem with trying to talk about colloquial forms in print - sorta like the user the other day asking about what to read to improve their speaking ability!

Answer (score 0):

[***that***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/that) is used as an adjective, sense 3:

> 3) designating the person or thing mentioned or understood   ⇒ "that woman is Mary; that pie tastes good"

so yes it does modify the noun.

Otherwise in your examples (assuming Jane Austen is the author), 1a should be:

> I have never heard of *that* **Jane Austen book**.

*that* is mentioning a particular *Jane Austen book*

As such, 1b would be better as:

> I have never heard of *that* **book by Jane Austen**.

Ex. 2 is OK, *that* modifies *book*, since you could also say *I can't find that book*.